# I can't find the place and application that removes the slashes from URL in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, iis, model-view-controller

I want to have multiple slashes from an URL removed so that if someone searches for:

site.com///Home///Index// to be Permanent Redirected to site.com/Home/Index/ or at least gives a 404.

I tried from IIS to create some rewrite rules or even blocking rules:
[rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UInl4.png) and i figure it out after a while that the problem is before the request touching IIS, because in IIS the URL attend without multiple slashes.

I also tried to create a new project, and using IIS Express i encountered the same problem, if i check the url that gets into my app with a request like: http://localhost:55158///Home///Index , i get in my app: /Home/Index [on begin request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19fcv.png), but if i check in Fiddler the request is: [fiddler request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyPKi.png)

What can i do in order to remove the unnecessary slashes?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that because it's part of the hierarchical portion of the URL it's automatically converting the double slashes to a single slash because double slashes aren't allowed in that portion of the URL. Because URLs contain characters that aren't allowed in the hierarchical portion of the URL, it's best to specify it (suitably encoded) as part of the query string (if a GET request) or in the form parameters (for a POST).

http://localhost:37779/api/get/?url=http:%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, web browser and fiddler will only send single "/" to IIS side no matter how many "/" you input in the address bar. So you don’t need to use rewrite rules to remove "/".

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in RouteConfig in ASP.NET MVC.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: The problem isn't in the web app, it is in IIS because the multiple slashes are not visible anymore in the app because are removed in IIS web server (this is the first point where a request is mapped)